# Can't encrypt Instagram requests using Charles Proxy

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, instagram, charles-proxy

Last year [Facebook rolled out](https://twitter.com/payloadartist/status/1109289092150263809?s=20) setting that allowed community to entrypt traffic using user installed certificates. I've successfully enabled whitehat settings for instagram account associated to my facebook account, and set them as seen on image.

### [image][image]

I'm using Charles Proxy to monitor HTTPS traffic, however after applying these Instagram settings and enabling SSL proxying in Charles **I can't read any requests and every action on Instagram app results in error like `can't update feed`**. Disablind SSL proxying let's me use the app without errors, but all requests seen in Charles from Instagram are encrypted.

- I'm able to read requests from sites that doesn't use pinned
  certificates like [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/).
- On my mobile phone I
  downloaded Charles certificate from [chls.pro/ssl](http://chls.pro/ssl).
- [tutorial](https://github.com/aliforever/charles-proxy-instagram-requests) I've followed, however I didn't understand  and did not do part past *How to Find Version, VersionCode and Signature Key*

Is there something I forgot to do or have done wrong way? Thanks in advance for any advises.